# Why is my cupcake brownie like?

Tags: baking, cake, chocolate, brownies

I’m exploring different recipes and tweaking a few things to make a result I’m happy with. I finally found a perfect ratio for a vanilla cake but when I tried to alter it to chocolate I got a very brownie like result. How do I fix this?

Recipe contains: AP flour, CoCoa, BP, salt, milk, oil, butter, sugar and 2 eggs

Comment: I understand that you might want to keep your recipe to yourself while you perfect it ;) However, can you at least share the flour measurement and how much cocoa powder you're adding?

Comment: Am I understanding correctly that you added cocoa powder to your vanilla cake recipe?

Comment: Welcome to the site, there's no way to help you without your exact measurements and method. You need to edit and add those details.

Comment: thanks for specifying that there are **2** eggs, that changes everything :)

Comment: Is there an by baking soda or baking powder in the recipe?   If not, how are you getting lift for your cake?  (Whipped egg whites?  Something else?)

Answer (score 1):

Baking powder contains both a chemical leavener (baking soda) and the acid required to activate it. It is normally used instead of baking soda in recipes where there isn't enough acid to activate baking soda. Cocoa powder is very acidic. What may have happened is that the combination of cocoa powder and baking powder contained too much acid for the baking soda, which produced too much leavening, inflating your batter so much that it then fell, resulting in the dense, brownie-like product you got.